# Can't use POST method in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I have application that is on App Store.

While developing it, I tested in both Android and iOS.

It works perfectly fine in iOS, right now. However, in Android, I can't login using my RESTful service.

Here is the error visible in remote debug console;

[image: Google Chrome Console]

I don't know what does the error trying to tell me? I don't understand why it works in iOS, but not in Android; while it was working past days. I didn't change a thing.

When user hits to Login button, below method is executed;

```
this.loginService.Login(this.inputName, this.inputPassword).subscribe( () => {
  // Route user to home page!
});
```

The method above is implemented inside [login.service.ts](https://gist.github.com/oguzhand95/319a0693fa059e73c8d8773cf866932e). Inside this service, it uses the ApiService class which is defined in [api.service.ts](https://gist.github.com/oguzhand95/263183bbaccb7c7ba9625c3406333a8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a permission issue. Add these lines in your "platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml" file and try:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks! One last question;
If I add these lines to AndroidManifest, I think I need to add them every build with "ionic cordova run". Is there way to add these into config.xml or such?

Comment: I am glad I was helpful. You might need to check https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config